# java.io.NotSerializableException: android.app.PendingIntent

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am trying to create an instance of `AlarmManager` with `pendingIntent`, but I cannot understand where I am going wrong.

My android app implements a customer class (`eventHandler`) which is `Serializable`. I have converted the object of my class to a byte array in order to pass it as an extra into my alarm intent. The app starts and works fine, reading the byte array and creating the alarm intent in my object with pendingintent. The problem occurs when I try to start a second activity, get the object of my class (which is serializable) and then convert it to a byte array to be passed as an extra.

The code that is a problem is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EventWeatherActivity.class);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
                **out.writeObject(event);**
                out.flush();
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, data);
```

**out.writeObject(event);** - is the line causing the error. But event which belongs to eventHandler (Serializable) did run when the app began, so why is it an issue when I am starting another activity?

The error that I am getting is:

```
    W/System.err: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.app.PendingIntent
2020-03-21 10:26:43.440 7646-7646/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
2020-03-21 10:26:43.440 7646-7646/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
2020-03-21 10:26:43.440 7646-7646/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
2020-03-21 10:26:43.443 7646-7646/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
2020-03-21 10:26:43.443 7646-7646/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
2020-03-21 10:26:43.443 7646-7646/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
2020-03-21 10:26:43.444 7646-7646/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at com.example.scrollingtext.EventFragment$1.onItemClick(EventFragment.java:122)
```

In my customer class (eventHandler event):

```
                    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
                    out.writeObject(this);
                    out.flush();
                    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                    alarmIntent.putExtra("imw.notification", data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        bos.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                final int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: If `eventHandler` is Serialized why not just add the Object direct in `putExtra`?

Comment: Can you please provide `EventHandler` class?

Comment: As above, the eventHandler class is provided in the last code snippet. The line pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); is what causes the app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your `EventHandler` class contains `pendingIntent` field, which cannot be serialized. You should separate your `EventHandler` class and describe there only fields you want to serialize. Also please provide the whole listing of your `EventHandler` class to see what else can cause the problem. Your current listing is not full.

Comment: @imim First of all add `transient` modifier to your fields in `Notification` class. 
`private transient PendingIntent pendingIntent;`
`private transient Activity activity;`
`private transient Context context;`
`private transient AlarmManager manager;`

Comment: @imim And please add whole listing of your `eventHandler` class. Not only `processEvent` method

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pendingIntent cannot be serialized, but weirdly when the app initially runs, pendingIntent runs fine within eventHandler and an alarm IS created successfully. The problem comes about when I try to then get a copy of that eventHandler object and convert it into a byte array as above so that I can pass the eventHandler object to my second activity. If I comment out the creation of a pendingIntent and alarm, the app runs fine passing the eventHandler object between activities.

So, as mentioned above I seperated the Alarm creation into a "Notification" class:

```
public class Notifications implements Serializable {

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private int notification_period;
private String notification_interval;
private Activity activity;
private Context context;
private AlarmManager manager;
private eventHandler event;

public Notifications(eventHandler event, int notification_period, String notification_interval, Activity activity, Context context)
{
    this.notification_interval = notification_interval;
    this.notification_period = notification_period;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = context;
    this.event = event;
}

public void setAlarm()
{
    manager = (android.app.AlarmManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if(notification_period != -1 && !notification_interval.equals("-1")) {

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(event);
            out.flush();
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            alarmIntent.putExtra("imw.notification", data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        final int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if(notification_interval.equals("minute")) {
            manager.setRepeating(android.app.AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), notification_period*60*1000, pendingIntent);
        }
        else if(notification_interval.equals("hour")) {
            manager.setRepeating(android.app.AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() * android.app.AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR * notification_period, android.app.AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pendingIntent);
        }
        else if(notification_interval.equals("day")) {
            manager.setRepeating(android.app.AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() * android.app.AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * notification_period, android.app.AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }

        Log.d("alarm_set", notification_period + " " + notification_interval);
    }
    else {
        if(pendingIntent != null)
        {
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            Log.d("alarm_cancelled", pendingIntent.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

..and now with the above, in my eventHandler class:

```
public void processEvent() {

    try {

        dailyWeather dWeather = new dailyWeather(raw_weather);
        hWeather = new hourlyWeather(raw_weather);

        tag = event.get("Tag");
        start_date = event.get("Start Date");
        start_time = event.get("Start Time");
        end_time = event.get("End Time");
        location = event.get("Location");
        lat = event.get("Lat");
        lng = event.get("Lng");

        notification_period = Integer.parseInt(event.get("Notification Period"));
        notification_interval = event.get("Notification Interval");

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        LocalDate fromDate = LocalDate.parse(start_date, formatter);
        LocalDateTime localTime_fromTime = LocalDateTime.parse(start_date + " " + start_time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));
        LocalDateTime localTime_toTime = LocalDateTime.parse(start_date + " " + end_time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));

        if (DAYS.between(LocalDate.now(), fromDate) > 7) {
            bActive = false;
        }
        else if(LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(localTime_toTime)) {
            Log.d("Expired", "End time");
            bActive = false;
            bExpired = true;
            bContainsHours = true;
        }
        else {
            bActive = true;
            weather = dWeather.getWeather(start_date);

            if (!start_time.equals("0")) {
                bContainsHours = true;
            }

            if(notification_period != -1 && !notification_interval.equals("")) {
                notificationManager = new Notifications(this, notification_period, notification_interval, activity, context);
                notificationManager.setAlarm();
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Err", "Error appearing here");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

now the app crashed when I run it from the beginning, complaining that AlarmManager is not  serialized.

```
    java.io.NotSerializableException: android.app.AlarmManager
2020-03-22 12:22:50.371 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
2020-03-22 12:22:50.371 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
2020-03-22 12:22:50.372 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
2020-03-22 12:22:50.373 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
2020-03-22 12:22:50.373 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
2020-03-22 12:22:50.373 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
2020-03-22 12:22:50.373 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
2020-03-22 12:22:50.374 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
2020-03-22 12:22:50.374 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
2020-03-22 12:22:50.374 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
2020-03-22 12:22:50.374 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at com.example.scrollingtext.Notifications.setAlarm(Notifications.java:47)
2020-03-22 12:22:50.377 16593-16593/com.example.scrollingtext W/System.err:     at com.example.scrollingtext.eventHandler.processEvent(eventHandler.java:98)
```